# Can I add a toolbar icon to UWP Xamarin project?

Tags: image, xamarin, win-universal-app, toolbar, windows-10-universal

I have xamarin project I am working on with iOS, Android and just recently added UWP. The code I am referring to is as follows:

```
 public static void AddCartToToolbar(Page page)
       {
        ToolbarItem tbi = null;

        tbi = new ToolbarItem("cart", "shoppingcart.png", () =>
        {
            page.Navigation.PushAsync(new CartPageView());
        }, 0, 0);
        App.RootPage.ToolbarItems.Add(tbi);
    }
```

The UWP toolbar item gets added, i can see the text of the toolbar item and the link to the CartPageView works, but the icon does not appear.I have added "shoppingcart.png" to the root directory of my UWP project. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: have you found a solution for this? I am facing the same problem at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is put your shoppingcart.png in root of your UWP project and in Properties set Build Action as Content.

I recommend putting your images into folders, so they don't create mess in your UWP project (I have put my images for InspectionsView in InspectionList folder instead of putting 10 images directly in project root)

[Image properties and place in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJT7D.png)